# Getting "expected call-signature: 'printMe' to have a typedef" and I can't get rid of it

Tags: webpack, tslint

I have a simple function:

```
export function printMe() : number {
    console.log("Print me...");
    return 1;
}
```

and I get this linting error:

```
WARNING in ./src/print.ts
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js):
[1, 17]: expected call-signature: 'printMe' to have a typedef
```

What is wrong with it? I'd rather get it right than disabling the rule.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `number` instead of `Number`?

Comment: @mbj certainly is. Thanks. Same issue though...

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. The lint configuration must be a separate rule in `webpack` config. For instance

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                options: { /* Loader options go here */ }
            }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }, {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: ['ts-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
}
...
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. What did it look like before you fixed it?